# Accidentally revoked an iOS certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store

I just got an email from Apple that states that I revoked an certificate yesterday:

> Certificate: XYZ Development
>
> Any provisioning profiles that include this certificate are no longer valid and must be regenerated for future use.

I didn't revoked it or at least I didn't do it on purpose.
However I worked with Xcode (never used it before) yesterday and I also created a new provision profile that contained the "XYZ Development" certificate.

What mistake of mine could have lead to the revocation?

Comment: sometimes you have to refresh your account associated provisioning profiles in xcode preferences. Try deleting that one and using same identifier change the provisioning profile name  and re create a certificate. So that conflict may not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its totally fine, did you do it in Xcode? Then it fixed itself: revoked the old ones and renewed them. Don't need to worry about that.